# Grid level triggers that set grid's child properties

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger

Is it possible to define triggers at the grid level that update grid's child properties?

I tried something like that but without success:

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool PropertyA {get;set;}
    public bool PropertyB {get;set;}
}
```

(I omitted all the PropertyChanged stuff for brievety)

**XAML:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock x:Name="ControlA" Grid.Row="0" />

    <TextBlock x:Name="ControlB" Grid.Row="1" />

    <Grid.Triggers>
        <!-- Condition A -->
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding PropertyA}" Value="false"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding PropertyB}" Value="true"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter TargetName="ControlA" Property="Text" Value="Blah"/>
                <Setter TargetName="ControlB" Property="Text" Value="Blah"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <!-- Conditon B -->
        <MultiDataTrigger>
             <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding PropertyA}" Value="false"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding PropertyB}" Value="false"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter TargetName="ControlA" Property="Text" Value="Blah"/>
                <Setter TargetName="ControlB" Property="Text" Value="Blah"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <!-- Condition C -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PropertyA}" Value="true">
             <Setter TargetName="ControlA" Property="Text" Value="Blah"/>
             <Setter TargetName="ControlB" Property="Text" Value="Blah"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

But the compiler complains about

> The name "ControlA" is not recognized.
>
> The name "ControlB" is not recognized.
>
> The member "Text" is not recognized or is not accessible.
>
> The member "Text" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to define triggers at the grid level that update grid's child properties?

No. Setting the `TargetName` of a `Setter` only  makes sense in a `ControlTemplate` where there is an element with a matching name.

Generally speaking, a `Setter` can only set a property of the element to which the style or trigger is applied to.

What you should do instead is to create a style with triggers for the `TextBlock`(s), e.g.:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding PropertyA}" Value="false"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding PropertyB}" Value="true"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Blah"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TextBlock x:Name="ControlA" Grid.Row="0" />

    <TextBlock x:Name="ControlB" Grid.Row="1" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: I already thought about your solution (and will probably mark it as the answer), but it means that I will have to define a style for each TextBlock in my Grid (since each TextBlock is triggered in a different way by the conditions). And this means repeating the whole trigger stuff in each style. A bit redundant ... but I guess I will not have the choice ... And I have more than two TextBlock T_T.

Comment: If different logic applies to different `TextBlocks` then yes, unfortunately.